# MySQL view with AS

Tags: mysql, ms-access

This has probably been answered in one of the several items I have read on here, but if so I am obviously too obtuse to realise it, in which case my apologies.
I am converting several MS-Access databases to MySql which has been going quite well but I have hit an issue with the following Access query (sql version):

```
SELECT tbl2019.Activity, tbl2019.Type, tbl2019.Unit, tbl2019.Amount AS [Current], tbl2018.Amount AS Previous, (([Current]/[Previous])-1)*100 AS Percentage
FROM tbl2019 
INNER JOIN tbl2018 ON tbl2019.Srl = tbl2018.Srl
WHERE (((tbl2019.Amount)>0) AND ((tbl2018.Amount)>0));
```

It appears to be with the 'AS' section and in vain attempts to sort it I have realised that MySql does not like [] and, that 'Current' is a reserved word and so (in MySql) changed it to 'thisyr' - with no effect.  So, what should the MySql view be, and for future understanding, why?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Table names like these give me shivers. Just fix your schema

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the elephant in the room...

```
SELECT x.Activity
     , x.Type
     , x.Unit
     , x.Amount Current
     , y.Amount Previous
     , ((x.Amount/y.Amount)-1)*100 Percentage
  FROM tbl2019 x
  JOIN tbl2018 y
    ON x.Srl = y.Srl
 WHERE x.Amount > 0 
   AND y.Amount > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks to your both.  
Strawberry, that worked and I understood it!!  
Both, the major jobs in this exercise are rationalising, tidying, and generally sorting out the whole database structures.  So, back to the grindstone!

Answer (score 0):

Current is a keyword - not a reserved word which means it's fine as an alias. You cannot use [] and you cannot access an aliased column in [Current]/[Previous just repeat the column name. and there's a lot of unnecessary parenthesis.